# PHP MySql: Checked Dynamic radio Box

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have this code for dynamic checked radio box:

PHP:

```
if ($author === 0) {$checked = 'checked';} else {$checked == '';}

if ($author === 1) {$checked = 'checked';} else {$checked == '';}

if ($author === 2) {$checked = 'checked';} else {$checked == '';}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" <?PHP echo $checked; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test" <?PHP echo $checked; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test" <?PHP echo $checked; ?> />
```

This way is true? What’s is a better/optimized Way?

Can I write any PHP function or class for save code and checked any radio box?

Comment: I suppose you use different variable names

Comment: Do you really want to check all three radio buttons if $author is 0,1 or 2?

Comment: "==" is not setting $checked, it's checking it. $checked = true; if($checked == true)...

Comment: Also, are these supposed to be checkboxes or radio buttons? If they are radio, then they can't all be checked.

Comment: If you want advice on optimization, perhaps ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It can save you some lines and unnecessary extra variables  if you look forward using the shorten `if` statement form. Example with the first `input` :

```
<input type="radio" name="test" <?php echo $author === 0 ? 'checked' : '' ?> />
```

Comment: What do you mean ? This `if`s are mutually exclusive for each group of buttons. No offense, maybe I am missing something, so please, elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to check a button if the author value relates to that input, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="0" <?php echo ($author == 0 ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1" <?php echo ($author == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2" <?php echo ($author == 2 ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?> />
```

Your currently checking all if the value is any.

Comment: You probably want to test $author, not set $author. :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML markup is wrong. With that HTML the user is able to select all of those radios. To make it so that the user can only select one of the radio buttons out of that group of options, change the names to all match, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="test1" <?PHP echo $checked; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test1" <?PHP echo $checked; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test1" <?PHP echo $checked; ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do:

```
<?php
    $checked = ($author >= 0 && $author <= 2 ? 'checked' : '');
?>
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="test" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test1" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="test2" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
```

Comment: Yes, but look at that HTML markup. The client is able to check every one of those radio buttons. To have a group of radio buttons for one question they all have to have the same `name=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    switch($author) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
             $checked = "checked";
             break;
        default:
             $checked = '';
    }
```